# Search All folders in one call?

Tags: mailkit

I want to search for by a date range across all folders.  Hopefully it would be a single call to mailKit.

I could get the full list of folders, and then search each folder for the given date range, but thats slow..

Is there a Deep Search option that i'm missing?

Any magic would be appreciated..

Comment: Gmail has an "All Mail" folder. If i search that it should work..

Comment: Works great.  

 return Service.GetFolder(SpecialFolder.All);

Answer (score 1):

Service.GetFolder(SpecialFolder.All);